# Compare two results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get an average of Customers total purchase and store it in @x

Then I want to store an average of Supplier total purchase and store it in @y

And then do some comparisons, It would be nice if anyone can help out. [image: And here is the table relations]

Comment: It would be nice if you posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you provide the sql you tried instead of just asking people to do your job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is quite hard to navigate your tables so i ll just post an example of something similar i did with my project:

```
  SELECT (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM `vw_on_report`) as x, (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM `vw_off_report`) as y
```